# Loading utf-8 file with pickle in Python2

Tags: python, utf-8

I am writing a script in Python that works on OSX (10.6) and uses Python 2.7.
My commands are:

```
    morphcache = codecs.open('file.txt','r','utf-8')
    morphology = pickle.load(morphcache)
    morphcache.close()
```

It uses a text file (utf-8) generated by another site which contains newlines and characters like č, š, ž etc.

Since it uses escaped characters it reports this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "createxml.py", line 38, in <module>
morphology = pickle.load(morphcache)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self) KeyError: 'sV\xc5\xbedeti\np1\nSVerb,\xc5\xbedeje,\xc5\xbedeti,\xc5\xbedeti,\xc5\xbedi,\xc5\xbedijo\np2\nsV\xc5\xbeupnik\np3\nVSu' make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I am searching for a solution how this would work - all solutions to the problem were saying to write text to a file in a different way (and not utf-8) first but I cannot do it, I already get the input file in such a form.

Or should this file first be read and written in another way to disk - and then reopened to be pickled?

Thanks.

Comment: Pickle files are binary content. Don't treat them as UTF-8 text.

Comment: Why are you treating the file as a pickle in the first place?

Comment: The script I am using is using pickle as its process. I am using this script for my language and trying to use it with my file - and it does not work.
https://code.google.com/p/apple-dictionary-plugins/source/browse/trunk/OpenThesaurus_Deutsch/createxml.py

Comment: How was the pickle file produced in the first place?

Comment: The pickle is produced from a language corpora and in textual terms it is equal to the files that work with it from German language. The only difference is the encoding of the files, German use ansi (basic), whereas using any other ansi (windows-1250, iso-8859-2) or utf-8 that is needed for the representation of letters č,š,ž,đ,ć etc. in the Slovenian words. So I wonder if such a text file could be reencoded in some way that it would be accepted by pickle.

Comment: Again: pickle is a binary format, not textual. It contains Python objects. You still haven't answered my questions. I can't help you without those answers.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle files are not text files. They contain Python object definitions (which could include `unicode` text objects, or `str` byte strings).

Open your file in binary mode and load that:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as morphcache:
    morphology = pickle.load(morphcache)
```

Comment: Thanks,unfortunately I still get an error:
  File "createxml.py", line 40, in <module>
    morphology = pickle.load(morphcache)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1196, in load_setitem
    key = stack.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: @slolibre: so your pickle file is incomplete or corrupted. Where did it come from in the first place?

Comment: The txt file I use is in the same form as the file the German language uses with this script:
https://code.google.com/p/apple-dictionary-plugins/source/browse/trunk/Morphologie_Deutsch/morphology-cache.txt

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't really mean anything to me. Can you update your question to show the code that produces the pickle file?

Comment: The pickle file is not produced by this script, it is gotten from a dictionary corpus, I have no influence on how it is produced.

Comment: But you could tell me where you got it, and how you downloaded it perhaps?

Comment: Hi, the German file was downloaded from the above code repository, the Slovenian one was generated automatically by a command line script using some linguistic and sed-like command tools to conform to this file standard. It was made 4 years ago and I do not have the script anymore.
I made it work with pickle, 4 years ago, but then my computer was stolen and I only have an older version of python script in which this didn't work so I am trying to figure out how I managed it 4 years ago. Due to my lacking skills and knowledge of python it must have been a simple solution.

Comment: German file:
https://code.google.com/p/apple-dictionary-plugins/source/browse/trunk/#trunk%2FMorphologie_Deutsch
Slovenian file:
http://ooo.siccla.net/gsi/libreoffice/slovenskimorphy.zip
Same script works with German file, but not with Slovenian one.

Comment: @slolibre: my apologies, I'm not sure how but I missed your links to the Google code project yesterday. I'll take a look now.

Comment: morphology-cache.txt is the result of a pickle command in the script from that folder in googlecode, not the input file for that script.

Comment: Just to add, that linked Slovenian file is in windows-1250 codepage (cp1250 in python), I also have an utf-8 version.

Comment: @slolibre: all I can say at this point is that your pickle file is indeed corrupted. *Why* it is corrupted I cannot tell. I'd alter the script to use `'wb'` (binary mode), at the very least, to try and avoid this issue.